# Looping until string length is divisible by 16. (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

So I was coding a program that takes the length of a given string, then loop through it until it is divisible by 16. I don't know what's going on in the program but it spits this error out:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of std::length_error' what():  basic_string::_M_replace_aux`

I expect an output of the text padded with 0's and the length being divisible by 16

Heres the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int check(string usrinp) {
    if (usrinp.length() % 16 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < usrinp.length(); i++) {
            if (usrinp.length() % 2 != 0) {
                usrinp.append(15 - usrinp.length(), '0');
            }
            else {
                usrinp.append(16 - usrinp.length(), '0');
            }
        }
    }

    cout << usrinp;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    check("1");
}
```

Comment: It's actually not obvious what's wrong with the program. Please describe clearly what output you get and what output you expect instead.

Comment: How can looping through a given string change whether its length is divisible by 16? Please give an example and explain step by step. Maybe it is a special kind of looping?

Comment: @Yunnosch i make a for loop then append the string given and pad it. Idk what is wrong with anything beyond that point.

Comment: @NotAidan, What does the debugger say?

Comment: It's pretty simple actually. The first glance will tell you what's wrong! `usrinp.append(15 - usrinp.length(), '0');` will try to append 0 at the 14th position of a string of length 1!

Comment: "i make a for loop then append the string given and pad it." So you do something in a for loop, probably appending something to something. What do you append to what? Did you verify the success of the appending? What does that which you append to look like before and after the attempt to append? Did you output that to check what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: @Yunnosch append just takes a given string and string length then adds a given amount of characthers.

Comment: Yes, that is also my understanding of "append". That does not however answer any of my questions.

Comment: @NotAidan, did you use the debugger as I suggested?

Comment: Thanks for not doing that comment standalone. But even as part of a comment which does give a hint, it still is unhelpful and dangerously far away from the ideal goal of a kind and polite comment.

Comment: Umm.. I didn't mean to be rude. Hope the OP understands that :) That's usually the problem with written stuff you know? You can't deliver it with the tonation with which it was intended

Comment: @NotAidan, what is the reason for writing `15 -` and `16 -`?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him the point is because say if the length was 17.. 17 + 16 = 33... 33 + 16 = 49. none of which come out to 0 when checking with a modulus calculation eg 49 % 16.  Instead if we added 15, we would eventually find a point when the modulus calculation comes out to 0. so on with "16"

Comment: NotAidan. You got several comments asking for one kind of clarification or another. I understand that this is overwhelming for you. Take your time and try to provide as much information and detail of your observations as possible. Here are very helpful hints on how to do that: [ask] and [mre] (especially the parts beyond code; input, output, expected output).

Comment: Probably the first useful comment on the post :) Kudos @Yunnosch

Comment: Not the first helpful one, but possibly the first one helpful on the level which OP needs to get started. Thanks for the compliment in any case.

Comment: Okay, so from what I understand, you want the length of the string to be divisible by 16. Why not start with a string of length 16 then?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him Its for an algorithm im building. The user gives in input. thats why i cant start with 16 because the user is entering something in. and i just pad it. simple.

Comment: That's fine. Will you please explain the algorithm (in the post; not in comments)? Please take a look at @Yunnosch's comment. People won't be able to help you unless you do that

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him the algorithm has nothing to affect this code in the post. i just need a way to add padding until the length is divisible by 16. thats all.

Comment: hmm... you probably need floor or ceil then

Comment: This is the point where I vote to close the post for lack of details and clarity. Sorry, please take the hints on how to improve your post more seriously. Don't worry; if I am the only one perceiving your post as unanswerable, then nothing will happen. And even if two other users agree with me, you still can improve the qustion and get it reopened. Good luck.

Comment: @NotAidan -- This really has little to do with strings.  I give you a number, and ask you to give me the next number evenly divisible number by 16 from that number.  In that description, where do you see the need to write a loop to figure out the answer?  It's just a little math using modulus.  Then it's a simple `std::string s;... s.resize(your_answer, '0');`.  No loops whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what question is asking about. So I implemented two interpretations of your question.

First variant, when you have to make a multiple of 16 by repeating a string, then you just have to use [LCM (Least Common Multiple)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), your target string size is equal `target_size = LCM(original_string.size(), 16)`.

Second solution is when you have to pad a string to multiple of 16. Then your resulting size is equal to `target_size = (original_string.size() + 15) / 16 * 16`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/5YTe5Pn8s)

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string RepeatToMultiple(std::string const & s, size_t k) {
    size_t const cnt = std::lcm(s.size(), k) / s.size();
    auto r = s;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < cnt; ++i)
        r += s;
    return r;
}

std::string PadToMultiple(std::string s, size_t k, char fill = '0') {
    s.resize((s.size() + k - 1) / k * k, fill);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "abcde_";
    std::cout << "Original: (size " << s.size() << ") " << s << std::endl;
    auto r = RepeatToMultiple(s, 16);
    std::cout << "Repeated till multiple of 16: (size " << r.size() << ") " << r << std::endl;
    auto r2 = PadToMultiple(s, 16);
    std::cout << "Padded to multiple of 16: (size " << r2.size() << ") " << r2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Original: (size 6) abcde_
Repeated till multiple of 16: (size 48) abcde_abcde_abcde_abcde_abcde_abcde_abcde_abcde_
Padded to multiple of 16: (size 16) abcde_0000000000
```

Comment: So you also had to guess..... Let's see.

Comment: The question is just asking for the input string to be padded with 0s such that the length is divisible by 16. This solution seems to be repeating the input string multiple times.

Comment: @cigien It is not clear from question's description what is really needed. So waiting for author to clarify this... And his reply in comments here.

Comment: In that case, it's preferable to vote to close the question until OP clarifies it. Otherwise, we might end up with multiple answers solving different interpretations of the question.

Comment: @cigien Thanks for commenting on this. Just added second solution to my code for padding to multiple of 16. So now I implemented two variants. Up to Author to choose which variant is what he wants.

Comment: @Arty You're honestly the G.O.A.T for adding all of the options for me to try. the second option worked perfectly for me. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @NotAidan I'm lucky, great that among two options there was one that you needed! :)

Comment: @NotAidan BTW, if my answer was correct you may now or later decide to Accept and/or UpVote it. You can Accept it by Check-Mark at the top of my answer to the left hand-side. There is also Upper Arrow for UpVoting if you like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to calculate your padding correctly:

```cpp
int pad = 16 * (str.length() / 16 + 1) - str.length();
```

Example1:

> length of string = 4
> then required pad = 12

16 * (4 / 16 + 1) - 4 gives 12. Don't be mistaken by (4 / 16), it'll result in 0 for integer division.

Example2:

> length of string = 37
> then required pad = 11

16 * (37 / 16 + 1) - 37 gives 11.

---

Then you can use whatever function you require to append to the string.

```cpp
str.append(pad, '0');
```